# Преобразование типа указателя С

Tags: c

Имею код:

```
int a = 1065353216;
int* pa = &a;

printf("%d", *((float*)pa)); // Выводит 0
```

Почему на выводе 0? Я так понимаю, что sizeof(int*) == sizeof(float*), то есть рассматривается 4 байта информации, но интерпретируется бинарное представление этой информации как целочисленное, тогда на выводе должно быть 1065353216. В чем проблема?

P. S. бинарное представление:

1065353216: 00111111 10000000 00000000 00000000 (1.0 для IEEE754 for float)

Comment: Все время выводит 0? Какой компьютер, ОС и компилятор?

Comment: https://ideone.com/VDXY5K Непохоже 1852385832 на ноль...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, поведение вашей программы неопределенно, так как она нарушает strict aliasing. Нельзя обращаться к объекту типа `int` как к объекту типа `float`.

Во-вторых, поведение вашей программы неопределенно, так как передаваемый в функцию `printf` аргумент не соответствует используемому спецификатору преобразования. Функция `printf` ожидает получить `int` а вы передаёте аргумент типа `double`.

В-третьих, даже если два предыдущих UB отработают так, как и задумано, вы не учитываете *default argument promotions*. Аргумент типа `float` преобразуется к типу `double`. А значит в строке `printf("%d", *((float*)pa));` функция `printf` на самом деле получает значение типа `double` и пытается вывести первые четыре байта восьмибайтного аргумента (при условии, что тип `int` занимает 4 байта, а тип `double` занимает 8 байт).

Если переданное значение типа `double` равно `1.0`, то все 52 бита мантиссы 64 битного числа с плавающей точкой равны нулю. А значит первые четыре байта скорее всего также будут равны нулю (а могут быть и не равны нулю, если байты, составляющие объект типа  `double` хранятся в каком-то [необычном порядке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

[Пример](https://ideone.com/lSlnDn):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 1.0f;
    double b = a;

    uint32_t a32, b32;
    uint64_t b64;

    memcpy(&a32, &a, sizeof(a32));
    memcpy(&b64, &b, sizeof(b64));
    memcpy(&b32, &b, sizeof(b32));

    printf("a32 = %" PRIu32 "\n", a32);
    printf("b64 = %" PRIu64 "\n", b64);
    printf("b32 = %" PRIu32 "\n", b32);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
a32 = 1065353216
b64 = 4607182418800017408
b32 = 0
```

Таким образом, ваш код при "щадящей" обработке `UB` эквивалентен следующему:

```
printf("0");
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

по сути ваш код делает следующее:

```
int a = 1065353216;
int* pa = &a;

float* pb = (float*)pa;

float b = *pb;

printf("%d", b);
```

т.е. вы пытаетесь сделать следующее:

```
printf("%d", 1.0f);
```

и `0` выдает только потому, что вы передаёте не int, т.е. это такой способ просигнализировать об ошибке

> Warning   C4477   'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'float'

Comment: Хорошо, да, вы правильно описали мои мысли. Но почему на выводе 0? Спецификатор формата просто должен интерпретировать то значение, которое передается во втором аргументе printf(), так, как определено в спецификаторе. Внутреннее представление числа не менялось, должно быть 1065353216. Но в чем проблема???

Comment: Ну, это зависит от системы и компилятора. У меня x86 (AMD) 64-bit Linux, gcc 7.5.0 выводит случайные числа, поскольку при передаче в printf числа с плавующей точкой в качестве 2-го параметра оно грузится в %xmm регистр, а параметр целого типа (в соответствии с %d) printf берет из %edx регистра.

Comment: А он и не выводит 0, вообще говоря, так что вы придумываете какие-то обоснования тому, чего не происходит. Как тот физик (не помню кто из великих), который объяснил какой-то эффект. Ему и говорят - вы перепутали, эффект обратный... на что он радостно заявил - ну, так тогда объяснить его еще легче :)  https://ideone.com/VDXY5K  Тут вообще-то столько UB, что...

Comment: в VS выводит 0, история про физика понравилась - как в анекдоте не выиграл, а приграл, не миллион, а 3 рубля :)

Answer (score 2):

несоотвествие типов приводит к неопределённому поведению. `gcc` с `printf` преобразует тип `float` в `double`, затем печатает.

код :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a = 1065353216;
int* pa = &a;

printf("%d\n", *((float*)pa)); // Выводит 0
printf("%d\n", *pa);
}
```

ассемблер :

```
.LC1:
        .string "%d\n"
main:
        push    rax
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip] ; здесь float -> double
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     al, 1
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 1065353216 ; целые числа передаются через esi
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248 ; тут float константа числа
```

вывод :

```
-490767160
1065353216
```

ссылка :

https://godbolt.org/z/6on83T

Так как в первом `printf` компилятор не загрузил число в регистр `esi` будет печататься случайное число. У разных компиляторов всё по разному.